# Get SDWebImage Cache Image

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage

I would like to ask on how to get the downloaded image after the SDWebImageManager downloaded it. I have only the code to download it via URL, here's what I got:

```
let manager: SDWebImageManager = SDWebImageManager.sharedManager()
                        manager.downloadImageWithURL(NSURL(string: feedDetails.thumbnail), options: [],
                            progress: {(receivedSize: Int, expectedSize: Int) -> Void in
                                print(receivedSize)
                            },
                            completed: {(image, error, cached, finished, url) -> Void in

                                self.feedImage.image = image
                            }
                        )
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "how to get the downloaded image"? In your 'completed' there is a parameter called 'image' which contains your image.

Comment: As per my understanding my code above always download the image via the URL, what I want is after the initial download of image, it will not download it again. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `SDWebImageManager` class the `downloadImageWithURL:` method

> Downloads the image at the given URL if not present in cache or return
>   the cached version otherwise.

So if the image is present in cache you are already retrieving it with your code, instead of downloading from the web.

Comment: Does the setImageWithURL function do the same thing?

Comment: Yes, the sd_setImageWithURL function use the downloadImageWithURL method of the SDWebImageManager class, so the logic is exactly the same.

Comment: Can I ask what's their difference.

Comment: With downloadImageWithUrl you download an UIImage while sd_setImageWithUrl downloads an image and set it to the imageView. If you only want to display the image you can go with sd_setImageWithUrl, downloadImageWithUrl can be useful if you want to do something with the image downloaded before shopping it.

Answer (score 9):

As far as I know (I just looked up the author's Git page) there is the following method to directly access an image which is stored inside the cache-

You can use the *SDImageCache* to store an image explicitly to the cache with the following code:

```
[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] storeImage:myImage forKey:myCacheKey];
```

Where *myImage* is the image you want to store and *myCacheKey* is a unique identifier for the image.

After you stored an image to the cache and want to use that image, just do the following:

```
[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] queryDiskCacheForKey:myCacheKey done:^(UIImage *image) {
    // image is not nil if image was found
}];
```

*This code is Objective-C code, you have to "convert" it to swift yourself.*

I hope I could help you!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for answer @beeef but SDWebImage has been updated some part of code:
Save image:

```
 [[SDWebImageDownloader sharedDownloader] downloadImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:string] options:SDWebImageDownloaderUseNSURLCache progress:nil completed:^(UIImage *image, NSData *data, NSError *error, BOOL finished) {

        if (image && finished) {
            // Cache image to disk or memory

            [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] storeImage:image forKey:@"img_key" toDisk:YES completion:^{
                //save
            }];
        }
    }];
```

Get image from disk cache:

```
 [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] queryCacheOperationForKey:@"img_key" done:^(UIImage * _Nullable image, NSData * _Nullable data, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
        [self.imageV setImage: image];
    }];
```