# SDWebimage - How Refresh cache works?

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage, image-loading, swift4.2

I have an application uses SDWebimage for listing images asynchronously to a table view. Sometimes after continuously refreshing the table view, some of the images are not loaded. Is there any way to handle this issue?

Comment: Have you checked the url in browser which is not loading in tableview.

Comment: Just check image URL, Sometimes If image url contains space, image won't load.

Comment: @Akshara Unnikrishnan, you may get help in here. https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/issues/363

Comment: refer this link:-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37007553/get-sdwebimage-cache-image

Comment: image store to local then after next time to load image in local database